# How to solve these simultaneous equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

I've stumbled upon a very good simultaneous equation with 4 variables and 4 equations, the are as follows

\begin{array}{r l}
bc+3d+15a-db-15c-3b=60 & (1) \\
d-15c=0 & (2) \\
3a-b= -6 & (3) \\
b-d-c+a=0 & (4)
\end{array}

Just need the values and how to to them.. not case sensitive just in case
Thanks

Comment: Where did you “stumble” upon this system of equations?

Answer (score 2):

From $(2)$,
$$d=15c\ \ \ \ldots(5)$$
Also from $(3)$, $b=3a+6$. Putting this and $(5)$ in $(4)$,
$$3a+6-15c-c+a=0$$
$$4a-16c+6=0$$
$$a = 4c-\frac32\ \ \ \ldots(6)$$
So$$\begin{align}
b&=3\left(4c-\frac32\right)+6\\
&=12c+\frac32\ \ \ \ldots(7)
\end{align}$$
Taking values of $a$, $b$ and $d$ from $(5)$, $(6)$ and $(7)$ and putting in $(1)$, we get a quadratic equation in $c$. I hope you can take it from here.

*Note:* You can do this by solving any three variables with respect to the fourth one. I just solved $a$, $b$ and $d$ w.r.t. $c$ because it seemed easier.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: use the last three equations to solve for three variables in terms of the fourth.  Substitute in to the first equation.